# Remove outlet from switch

Tags: electrical

I have a double light switch that controls the porch light and outlet below but only with only one of the switches.  What I want to do is remove the outlet from being controlled by the switch all together and install a single switch.  The top switch does nothing so I am guessing it is already wired wrong.  Also the outlet only has power when the porch light is on.  Therefore, on switch of the double switch is running everything.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes?

Answer (score 1):

First: don't guess: open up the box and see what is wired to the second switch.  Second: to provide direct power to the outlet, you just need to move its hot (usually black) wire to the input feed, rather than the output side of the switch.

EDIT: per the comment, I should have made it clear that you're not to wire directly to the switch itself, but rather, via wire nuts, to the incoming hot black wird.

Standard warning: if that isn't clear to you, you should bring someone in who's familiar with wiring rather than risk injury to yourself or the house.

Comment: I would not put two wires on a single switch terminal unless the switch is listed to do so, which is highly improbable.  Straighten 'em out and use a yellow wire nut.

Comment: @Harper  That is what I meant;  thanks for the note- I've edited accordingly